# OfficeJs - Get Font/Theme colors of excel/powerpoint file

Tags: excel, themes, office-js

How can i get excel/powerpoint theme colors in font settings via officeJs?

Is it possible at all?

I need first row, but if i get all rows it is not problem.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You may have a try Office.OfficeTheme API, see if this API works for you. the document can be found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.officetheme?view=word-js-preview,

```
function applyOfficeTheme(){
    // Get office theme colors.
    var bodyBackgroundColor = Office.context.officeTheme.bodyBackgroundColor;
    var bodyForegroundColor = Office.context.officeTheme.bodyForegroundColor;
    var controlBackgroundColor = Office.context.officeTheme.controlBackgroundColor;
    var controlForegroundColor = Office.context.officeTheme.controlForegroundColor;

    // Apply body background color to a CSS class.
    $('.body').css('background-color', bodyBackgroundColor);
}
```

if this doesnt work for you, that should be a new feature ask, and then you could submit your request in uservoice and upvote for this feature at https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback?category_id=163563. and upvote for this feature. thanks for your support

Comment: Yes, i have read this document, but i think that officeTheme property return office theme instead of design.

This property return 4 colors instead of color tables (many color)

Comment: Thanks, Peter, I think you may need to submit this request to the UserVoice. we would prioritize this based on the voting

Comment: i did it. Thank you, your answer and help